# Register effects with NGRX

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

How To register CompanyEffects in AppModule, After AppConfigService response received from server.

effect registration in AppModule

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([CompanyEffects]),
```

CompanyEffects

```
export class CompanyEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private companyService: CompanyService,
        private env: AppConfigService,
    ) {
    }
}

@Effect()
    loadTeams$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(companyActions.CompanyActionsTypes.ALL_TEAMS_REQUEST),
        mergeMap(() =>
            this.companyService.teamList().pipe(
             ...
            )
        ));
```

AppConfigService

```
export class AppConfigService {
    public appConfig: AppConfig;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    loadAppConfig(): Promise<any> {
        const http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);
        let configUrl = "/api/data/config";

        const promise = http
            .get(configUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then((data: AppConfig) => {
                this.appConfig = data;
                return data;
            });
        return promise;
    }      
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar situation. Using backend server to feed configuration and not using Angular's environment files for it - how can I solve the above issue

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it.

You can only update the `CompanyEffects` to skip / delay the actions until `this.env.appConfig` has been present.